# Different go.sum entries for different Go versions

Tags: go

When I generate `go.sum` with go 1.16, and try to build it with go of a different version (1.13 in my case), I get `SECURITY ERROR`:

```
verifying github.com/tredoe/osutil@v1.1.1/go.mod: checksum mismatch
    downloaded: h1:fx79htI3WZA9Ep4jphLFq06l3iRDimfOWTrkKOz+OAA=
    go.sum:     h1:wHEjPMepmXQXkZhf9H4sQcCtmC45KuFo5VR97zG9/dY=

SECURITY ERROR
This download does NOT match an earlier download recorded in go.sum.
The bits may have been replaced on the origin server, or an attacker may
have intercepted the download attempt.

For more information, see 'go help module-auth'.
```

Then I fix (remove the entry and run `go mod tidy`) `go.sum` and try to build it again. It works with 1.13, but the problem appears then with 1.16.

So there should be some incompatibility between Go 1.13 and 1.16 (not sure exactly when it was introduced, so don't know about 1.14 and 1.15).

Currently, as a workaround, I added this to my build scripts:

```
sed -i /osutil/d go.sum \
&& go mod download github.com/tredoe/osutil
```

but it is not a real solution, of course.

How am I supposed to fix this problem?

Comment: Ask this on golang-nuts.

Comment: @Volker: Good idea. Done!

Comment: golang-nuts thread: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/a_cHjXkPWYg

Comment: Issue in the osutil repository: https://github.com/tredoe/osutil/issues/13
Maybe the author of the repository will help, but there was no feedback so far